# Does downvoting someone's question causes reputation loss?

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I just downvoted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771520/why-232-1-and-not-232). It reduced my reputation by 1 point.

So I guess downvoting someone's question causes reputation loss, right?

Here's the [screenshot](http://img864.imageshack.us/f/86843145d.png/).

Comment: This is by design. Without it, it would be very easy to create a dummy account and sabotage another user's rep. It also encourages constructive comments/edits over downvoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, downvoting questions or answers cause 2 points loss for the author of the question/answer, and 1 point loss for the downvoter.

This is not a bug, so you can remove `bug` tag from your question. This behavior is also documented in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> those votes will cause you to gain (or, in rare cases, lose) reputation:
>
> [...]
>
> post is voted down    -2  (-1 to voter)

Comment: If more number of people are down voting a certain question, then it should be good if the reputations are awarded back or not reducing from who are down voting.

Comment: @tenten: when the answer is really bad, the users don't only downvote it, but vote to remove the answer. Once the answer is deleted, the reputation is awarded back to the downvoters.